# Targeting both ID and class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a feeling this is an easy one, but I'm still learning. I need to modify this jQuery snippet to affect **.playing1** but haven't found the proper way of doing so. I would need to target both the ID and class. I've attempted to replace #fitin with my ID and class, but the code continues to fail outside it's original form.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#fitin div').css('font-size', '1em');

    while( $('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height() ) {
        $('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
    }

});
```

**Simplified HTML**

```
<body>
  <script src="fitin.js"></script>

  <div id="block-views-nowplayingtest-block">
      <div class="playing1">
          <!--My Text -->
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#block-views-nowplayingtest-block div.playing1
{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1.5em;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

Note: I did not write the original JQuery and unfortunately I cannot locate the source at this time.

Edit:typo

Comment: I see no element with the ID `fitin`.

Comment: when you know the id of an element you don't need to address it with a class as well. You may find all children with a certain class like this: `$("#id .child-class")`...

Comment: That is my dilemma. I need to modify the jQuery to affect [#block-views-nowplayingtest-block div.playing1], but have been continuously unsuccessful.

Comment: then `$("#block-views-nowplayingtest-block div.playing1")` should be just fine

Comment: Are you stuck with that selector? is there any reason that you need to qualify that .playing1 is a div? This is a gnarly selector - and if you can, you would be better off changing it to something else.

Comment: Check out http://fittextjs.com/ - maybe this is what you want, and with documentation and stuff.

Comment: This code is all experimental at this time. I don't remember why I used playing1 but it's certainly wont stay that way if it leaves my sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to affect the class `.playing1`, use either:

1. `.playing1` (all elements in that class)
2. `div.playing1` for (all divs in that class).

If you want that specific child element, and no other elements, use either:

1. `#block-views-nowplayingtest-block .playing1` (all elements in that class that are children of that id)
2. `#block-views-nowplayingtest-block div.playing1` (all divs in that class that are children of that id)

Always keep in mind how specific you are trying to be when targeting a class, and if the class you've defined will be used on a variety of elements types or just one type.

Comment: I'll try this once I get back home. I'm almost sure that was what I tried first, but I'm certainly willing to give it another go.

Comment: Would be curious to know what you are trying to achieve, as there is probably a more efficient strategy than a `while` loop.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to get responsive text based on parent size, but it totally crashes the browser if you put it in a fiddle.

Comment: I'm trying the automatically scale my font-size to always fit it's parent container. The dimension of the div is static but the length of the text will change often and it cannot overflow. I haven't succeeded in writing the code myself so this snippet was plan B. Hope that makes sense.